# Incorrect Image class used during casting; how do I do it correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

public Image Image { get; set; }

```
Image=(Image)randomImageFromCommentsClass.Image;
```

I get this:

Cannot convert System.Drawing.Image to System.Web.UI.WebControls

I think I imported the wrong namespace (System.Drawing)..That may be the mistake. What I am trying to do is to convert the Image type from database to an Image object.

```
public class Comments
{
  public Image Image { get; set; }
      Image = DBNull.Value.Equals(dr["Avatar"]) ? null: (Image)dr["Image"];
```

This image property above is from a different class code file in visual studio 2010.

Somehow the cast fails..how do i fix that?

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like the wrong namespace. You can use the fully qualified version... just include the namespace in type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely no way you will be able to cast unless the object you are casting is an instance of the other object.

You can covert the byte array to an Image with this snipet:

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn){
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage
}
```

To show a dynamically created image with your WebControl you will need a handler more info here:

[Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)

Comment: Whats the type of the Image that is inside the the database? Does it belong to Drawing or WebControls namespace

Comment: It belongs to neither, images are stored in databases as byte arrays.

Comment: lol..Anyway to convert the byte array to an image?!? from Drawing class and then put it into Image webcontrol?

Comment: Alright. So this will retun an image that i will be able to cast to Drawing.Image... How then i can convert Drawing.Image to WebControl.Image?

Comment: You cannot directly convert a Drawing.Image to a WebControl. You will need a handler for that. I edited my post with information on this.

Comment: even if you convert byte[] to Drawing.Image you can not assign it to image control.  if you want to assign an Image to ImageControl in asp.net you will have to create a temporary Image so that you can assign it to Image.ImageUrl

Comment: hmmmm.. so i need that to do something like this: Image.ImageUrl=tempImage.ImageUrl;

Comment: Yes you would need to use the ImageUrl for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are talking about SQL's Image datatype then these images are stored in `byte[]` format so u  will need to take the data from database into byte[] variable and then using `FileStream` create a new temporary Image file in your fileSystem and then assign it to any image control or whatever you want to do.

are you trying to assign image stored in database to Image Control in ASP.NET?

I dont think there is any way to convert Byte[] to System.Drawing
so here is the solution i use:

```
byte[] ImageData;
string filePath = @"~\Image.jpeg";  //path or temporary Image
using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand getImageCmd = new SqlCommand("/* your SQL query to get Image from database*/ ", con);
    ImageData = (byte[])getImageCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
}
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
using (fs)
{
    foreach (byte b in ImageData)
    {
        fs.WriteByte(b);
    }
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}

ImageControl.ImageUrl = "~/Image.jpeg"; // assign that temp Image to Image Control
```

Comment: Yeah. I try to do this 1) get the image out of the database 2) convert it to Image Drawing 3) Convert it to the web control.. or may be if there is a short cut simply convert it to the Drawing image ..straight away

Comment: I will try it. At a bit later time..thanks for providing me with a direction

Answer (score 0):

This article shows how to create an Image control that will accept an image directly from memory with no file saving or handlers required. Hope it's helpful.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/e1a14e2c-e746-4bed-a552-24c632bd2709/aspnet-inmemory-image-control-with-builtin-resizing-of-posted-file.aspx